# Magento 2 add custom css to custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, css

We have a Magento 2.1 website with a theme we bought. We have the theme in "default aka production" mode. we are customizing the theme so create a child theme. Now we want to create a custom css to keep our custom css separate from the themes css. So we created a custom css file names customcss.css in  a directory

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/web/css
```

Then we edited the file named default_head_blocks.xml adding

```
<css src="css/customcss.css" />
```

to the file under all the other calls to css files. We then cleared the cache in magento and cleared our browsers cache and when to the website and our issue is when we view the source for the website it does not seem to be loading the customcss.css file. It looks like when we recompile/re-deploy files the customcss.css file is not moved to where ever all the "deployed" files are moved to?? So not sure how to correct this so that when we on the CL recomplie/redeploye the css file is kept?

Comment: Which mode you are using ?

Comment: We have our site set to default mode